# Bicep for connection string in App service

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I have an app that has a bicep file (to deploy azure app service) which calls a template module(app service template) in another repository. The template module refer multiple modules in same repository. It calls one module for app service plan, one for app insight, one for app service.

Now I would like to have the app service have a connection string setting to be added which I think can be achieved with resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' but it needs a parent parameter which is resource name. I am struggling to figure out a way to achieve this.

```
//main bicep of repository 1

module appServiceTemplateModule '../appservicetemplate.bicep' = {
  name: ''
  params: {    
    aspName: 'aspName'
    aiName: 'aiName'
    asName: 'asName'
    appSettings: [      
      {
        name: ''
        value: 
      }
      {
        name: ''
        value: 
      }
      {
        name: 'ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION'
        value: '~2'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
//Template Repo

//paramaters

//variables

module appserviceplanModule 'appserviceplan.bicep' = {
  name: hostingModule
  params: {
  }
}

module appInsightModule 'appinsights.bicep' = {
  name: aiModule
  params: {
  }
}

module appServiceModule 'appservices.bicep' = {
  name: asModule
  params: {
  }
  dependsOn: [ appserviceplanModule, appInsightModule ]
}
```

Template repo has individual biceps being called.

I want the bicep files to remain generic so I do not want the appservices.bicep file to have Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01 as a resource which can select the app service resource as parent. Stuck with how to achieve this.

Please let me know if any additional details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a condition to determine whether or not to create it... `if(!empty(connectionstrings))`

I'd probably put all the logic in your appservicetemplate.bicep file and add a new `connectionstrings` parameter.

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location

param connectionstrings object = {
  name: {
    value: 'value'
    type: 'SQLAzure'
  }
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-12-01' = {
  name: 'plan'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'F1'
    capacity: 1
  }
}

resource webApplication 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-15' = {
  name: 'webappname-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
  location: location
  tags: {
    'hidden-related:${resourceGroup().id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/appServicePlan': 'Resource'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
  }

  resource config 'config' = if(!empty(connectionstrings)) {
    name: 'connectionstrings'
    properties: {
        name: {
          value: 'value'
          type: 'SQLAzure'
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you GordonBy I did think of doing this... But for this approach I have one clarification (a dumb one!) In your above example is connectionstrings the name of the variable holding connection string value and what is name in properties section?

Comment: If my app setting name holding the connection string value is MyDBContext where will it go? I can handle if it should go in the place of name: 'connectionstrings' but not sure how to if it is under properties name. And if it goes in the place of name: 'connectionstrings' in that case if I have multiple connection strings would I have multiple resource config declarations within my app service

Comment: Please ignore my questions I got it, will implement and update accordingly, thanks again!

Comment: Cool, glad it makes sense.  Another way if you wanted to keep it out of the module, and avoid the pain of the `parent` property is to set it in the name `name: 'webapp/connectionstrings'`. I'd still do it the way i suggested in the answer though 

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get this done which I tried as well
You can create this object from your calling main bicep that calls template module

```
param connectionStringsObj array = []

resource appServiceResource 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 
  location: 
  
  properties:{
    serverFarmId: 
    siteConfig:{
      alwaysOn: 
      ftpsState: 
      netFrameworkVersion: 
      appSettings: 
    
    connectionStrings: [for connectionstring in connectionStringsObj: {
      name: connectionstring.name
      connectionString: connectionstring.connectionString
      type: connectionstring.type
    }]
  }
    httpsOnly: 
  }
}
```

Main bicep that calls can have it declared like this

```
param connectionStrings array = [
    {
        name: 'MyDbContext1'
        connectionString: ''
        type: 'SQLAzure'//or anything else tha is offered
    }
    {
        name: 'MyDbContext2'
        connectionString: ''
        type: 'SQLAzure'//or anything else tha is offered
    }
]
```